# WordPress mediaelement video sizing not responsive when viewed in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

We have a problem with our WordPress. We are using mediaelement.js .

So there is a problem with the `<video>`-tag and Firefox. If i reduce the window size the video is not getting smaller. In Google Chrome and IE it's no problem if I reduce it there the window the video is getting smaller.

I have no idea what I can do. I tried so many things but nothing happend :-(.

So we are using the [video .... ] tag in a textblock in WordPress.

I tried for example "style: width:100%; height:100%;" but nothing happens in Firefox.

How can I ensure the video resizes correctly in Firefox?

Comment: Can you check which video format you are using?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the *Browser and Device support* chart on the website of mediaelement.js it might be that the video you are using has a format that can play via html5 video in IE and Chrome but not Firefox, so Firefox has to use Flash which in turn won't resize.